# How do I send messages that users can only view inside the app?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to know if it's possible to send users direct messages inside an app. Not sms to their phones but messages they only can view inside the app. Messages like an email that gets saved into an app's inbox, but they can't reply back, just one way communication? I hope it makes sense.
If so how can I go about doing it? I am using react native. Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [WebSockets API](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/WebSockets)

Comment: Thank you Gkucmierz I think this could be what I need, I will learn more about it. :)

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what kind of messages you want to send. Maybe Push Notifications would do the trick for you. You can try [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) for this.

Comment: Push notifications don't get saved in an inbox (Do they??) I want a message that can be automatically stored but users can delete as well.